# Running into a Circular Import issue

Tags: python, django

I have two apps(front and lrnadmin) in project(portal) this is my root directory

[image]

the problem is that when I import the models in each other it gives me error
In this models I want Qualification as Foreign key that why I want import Qualification from lrnadmin.models
`this is my front.models.py`

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import expressions
from django.db.models.base import Model
from django.utils import timezone

from lrnadmin.models import Qualification

class Staff(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Staff."""
    # TODO: Define fields here
    nStaff = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    lrnQ = models.ForeignKey(Qualification, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    relQ = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    relE = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # Cv = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    # Doc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sec7 = models.ForeignKey(Sec7, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Staff."""

        verbose_name = 'Staff'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Staffs'

    # def __str__(self):
    #     """Unicode representation of Staff."""
    #     pass
```

and in this models I want User as Foreign key that why I want import User from front.models
`this is my lrnadmin.models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from front.models import User

class CentreCode(models.Model):
    """Model definition for CentreCode."""

    # TODO: Define fields here
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    centreCode = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    authorisation = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    registrationType = models.CharField(max_length= 20)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for CentreCode."""

        verbose_name = 'CentreCode'
        verbose_name_plural = 'CentreCodes'

    # def __str__(self):
    #     """Unicode representation of CentreCode."""
    #     pass
```

How Can I handle this

```
File "E:\lrn\portal\lrnadmin\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from front.models import User
  File "E:\lrn\portal\front\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lrnadmin.models import Qualification
ImportError: cannot import name 'Qualification' from partially initialized module 'lrnadmin.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (E:\lrn\portal\lrnadmin\models.py)
```

Comment: The error could not be a lot clearer: "most likely due to a circular import". If A imports B and B imports A, how do you expect that to work?

Comment: so what should I do.

Comment: Don't import A from B, if you need to import B from A, and vice versa. Either import both A and B from C and combine them there, or eliminate one of the imports. (or put everything in the same module - if they are interdependent like this, they're really one thing anyway)

Comment: one (dirty) workaround is delaying the import of A from B or vice verse. For example, if you're using B within a function in A, add a local `from B import ...` within the function where the import is being used. Though, should be noted that I would rather suggest refactoring the code to resolve the import issue.

Comment: I want a model of A in B and B in A. is there any solution

Comment: What @rv.kvetch says also works, but only if you don't actually call the thing that has the import from the code in the body of the module or the body text of any of the classes - which can lead to some pretty funky errors.

Comment: @HabibUrRehman Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). Towards the end of this section, the docs shows you a way on how to prevent this if you are using these imports for foreign keys. Do share your models if possible

Comment: Ok I am updating my question with models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "lazy-load" a model by using a string literal as described in the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), so for example with the `front` app's `User` model you can define it like:

```py
# Remove from front.models import User


class CentreCode(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey('front.User', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

Or if you defined `front.models.User` as a custom user model, it's highly suggested that you just reference the custom model using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` as described [**`here`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model):

```py
from django.conf import settings
# Remove from front.models import User


class CentreCode(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

Comment: my User is normal models class

Comment: class User(models.Model):
    """Model definition for User."""

    # TODO: Define fields here
    username = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(default="pending", max_length=20)
    role = models.CharField(default="centre", max_length=20)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default= timezone.now)

Comment: Did you also specify it in the settings using `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: I created the main AUTH_USER_MODEL is another class model (Login)

Comment: In that case try to use the first approach with the string literal. Although I have to say I'm not sure why `Login` is used as the user model but that's up to you

Comment: Thanks for giving your answer please elaborate..
 'front.User' why it is not 'front.models.User'

Answer (score 0):

you can try out the get_model which will avoid importing the model at run time

```
   from django.apps import apps
   qualification_model = app.get_model('lrnadmin', 'Qualification')
```

OR

you can try to import the model inside the function instead of importing at  module level